# Horizontal tangent line

Tags: calculus

I need some verification on this problem, not sure if I did it right.

Find all points on the level surface

$$x^3 − 3x − y^2 + 4y + z^3 = 10$$

where the tangent plane is horizontal.

So I take the gradient,

$$f_x = 3x^2 -3$$

$$f_y = -2y + 4$$

So set them to $0$ and solve, getting $x = 1, x= -1, y = 2$

This is the part that confused me. I know you plug $x$ and $y$ back in to find the $z$ component, but this is the first problem I've done where I have two values for a variable. So I plugged both $x$ values in, getting $(1,2,2)$ and $(-1, 2, \sqrt[3]{4})$

Would this be correct, or am I off base?

Comment: Why your gradient has only two components? I think that somehow $z$ enters here also or am I wrong?

Comment: Remember that finding a horizontal tangent plane is the two-dimensional analogue of finding a horizontal tangent line to a curve for a single-variable function.  If you graph this surface, you'll see that the section in the plane  $ \ y \ = \ 2 \ $ has both a local maximum and a local minimum.  So finding two (or more!) points with horizontal tangent planes to a surface isn't unreasonable.  [Inserting  $ \ y \ = \ 2 \ $ into the surface equation gives an explicit function  $ \ z \ = \ ( \ 6 \ + \ 3x \ - \ x^3 \ )^{1/3} \ $ , for which it's easy to show that you've found the right extrema.]

Comment: @Karl  You would be right about the gradient in general.  For _this_ level surface, it is possible to express the equation as an explicit function $ \ z \ = \ f ( x, \ y ) \ $ , so we can drop the term for the partial derivative with respect to  $ \ z \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least it seems right to me. If you take the gradient, then you get $\nabla f = (3x^2-3, -2y+4, 3z^2)$. Since the gradient is normal to surface, if tangent is horizontal, then gradient is vertical, i.e. $f_x=0$ **and** $f_y=0$, and you got the solution. Notice the **and** here, you must satisfy both condition. Your solution are ($x_1$ **or** $x_2$) **and** $y$, which means $(x_1, y)$ **or**(edited, sorry I didn't notice this mistake until now) $(x_2, y)$